# Rails multistep model creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, multipartform-data

What is a good way to implement multistep creation of a model in rails?  By this I mean, instead of having one long form, the user fills out one part, and then fills out the next part on another page.  Essentially, this is a multi-part form with each part on a different page.

How do I save the user input for each part of the form?  I am doing validations on the fields as well; how do I handle validation in Rails so that each part of the form is validated separately ? (If I put all of the validations in the model, the form will never validate successfully, as the fields that the user cannot see yet are never filled out.  Yes, javascript is an option; I want to handle validation in Rails so that it will work even with javascript disabled).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ryan Bates did a screencast directly related to this, I highly recommend you check it out:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

Answer (score 2):

The wizardly gem is designed to do this. It's very handy. My fork:
https://github.com/paulschreiber/wizardly

Note that it does not work with Rails 3.x; it requires Rails 2.3.x or older.

Comment: Do you know any alternatives to wizardly for Rails 3?